# A tough one: show that this is not differentiable at any point in R

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Here's the question:

Define  $\phi: \ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
$$ \phi(x) = \begin{cases}x & 0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}\\ 1-x & \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}.
$$

And then extend periodically to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(x) = \phi(x+1)$. Now define $$S_m(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^m \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^i \phi(4^ix)$$

Show that S, the limit function of $S_m(x)$ is not differentiable at any point in $\mathbb{R}$. You are allowed to define sequences somewhat implicitly, such as "let $a_n$ be the largest multiple of $4^{-n}$ which is less than or equal to $\pi$."

My thoughts: 
I'm not sure where to start. My guess is that we can choose two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ where $a_n$ is monotone increasing and $b_n$ is monotone decreasing and they both converge to an arbitrary point $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(b_n) - f(a_n)}{b-a} \neq f'(c)$. But I'm not sure how to define those sequences. Or if that would even be sufficient.

Comment: The way you described $S$ looks like it only deals with numbers with the form $k4^{-n}$. In that case the domain is discrete and don make sense to talk about derivatives.

Comment: Good catch, that was poor explaining on my part. I found the limit function in a separate problem and thought it might be helpful, but this problem is actually referring to $S_m(x)$. I've corrected my original post.

Comment: Is it supposed to be "$S_\infty$ is not differentiable " ....

Comment: Yes -- S is the limit function of $S_m(x)$. I should have made that clearer. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, $\left| \phi (x)-\phi (y) \right|\le \left| x-y \right|$. Then, consider
\begin{align}
\frac{S(x+\delta )-S(x)}{\delta }=\frac{1}{\delta }\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{{{\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)}^{i}}\left[ \phi ({{4}^{i}}x+{{4}^{i}}\delta )-\phi ({{4}^{i}}x) \right]}.\end{align}We choose $ \delta\ ={{\delta }_{n}}=\pm\frac{1}{4}\cdot{{4}^{-n}}$, and guarantee that there are no "turning point" in the interval $[{{4}^{n}}x,\ {{4}^{n}}x+{{4}^{n}}{{\delta }_{n}}]$. And thus, $\forall i>n$, $\phi ({{4}^{i}}x+{{4}^{i}}{\delta }_{n} )-\phi ({{4}^{i}}x)=0$. Hence,
\begin{align}
  & \left| \frac{S(x+{{\delta }_{n}})-S(x)}{{{\delta }_{n}}} \right|=\left| \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{{{\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)}^{i}}\frac{\phi ({{4}^{i}}x+{{4}^{i}}{{\delta }_{n}})-\phi ({{4}^{i}})}{{{\delta }_{n}}}} \right| \\ 
 & \ge {{3}^{n}}-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}{{{3}^{i}}}=\frac{{{3}^{n}}+1}{2}  
.\end{align} Now, we can obtain a contradiction.